# How to get value from adjacent column in GridView after ComboBox item checked?

Tags: c#, javascript, gridview, telerik

I have a question regarding Telerik RadComboBox in ASP.Net GridView Control.

Please find my code fragment on below:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="papPanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvTestGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvTestGrid_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column1">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Col1")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column2">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbItem" runat="server" CheckBoxes="true" AutoPostBack="false"
                            OnClientItemChecked="rcbItemOnClientItemChecked">
                            <items>
                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="1" Text="Item A" />
                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="2" Text="Item B" />
                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="3" Text="Item C" />
                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="3" Text="Item D" />
                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="3" Text="Item E" />
                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="3" Text="Item F" />
                            </items>
                        </telerik:RadComboBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

There is 2 columns in my GridView, I wanted to get the value from "Column1", by using JavaScript or jQuery when OnClientItemChecked event trigger on "Column2" on the same row.

[image]

For example, after value checked on the ComboBox control in row 1, I wanted to get the value "1".

Please help, thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the online demo of this control set [telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/programming/clientevents/defaultcs.aspx)
OR you can try the sample below:

```
       function onItemChecked(sender, args) {
            var checked = args.get_item().get_checked();
            *var rowIndex=sender.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex; //please debug your code to find YOUR rowIndex*
            **var rowIndex=sender._element.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex //wish this code works**
            var gdview=document.getElementById("<%=gvTestGrid.ClientID %>");
            var value=gdview.rows(rowIndex).cells(0).innerText;
       }
```

Comment: Hi Eugene,the sender.parentNode property seem to be unavailable for radcombobox

Comment: There is no environment for me to check the code, so I suggest that you can try debug your code to find the container information, such as: sender.Parent / sender.Container / sender.object.parentNode